# Who we are going to meet vs. who are we going to meet

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a dilemma regarding construction of this sentence:
Uploading a picture of your dog lets us know who are we going to meet.
Should it be: Uploading a picture of your dog lets us know who we are going to meet?
Or something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

> Uploading a picture of your dog lets us know who we are going to meet.

because it is an affirmative sentence, not a question.